# Find / highlight double triple source line of an array

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to highlight or find all double lines of an array using PhpStorm?

for example

```
$x = array();

$x['one'] = 'Some text';
$x['two'] = 'Some other text';
$x['three'] = 'Also some text';
$x['one'] = 'Also some other text';
$x['four'] = 'text text';
... and so much more
```

need to hihglight the `$x['one']` because is double or triple on the source.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to perform this check in phpstorm in your construction. Only with array declaration like:

```
  $a = [
    '1' => 1,
    '1' => 2,
  ];
```

Phpstorm inform you about array key duplication